# What NuGet package contains System.Xml.UniqueId?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In .NET 4.5, the `UniqueId` class lived in System.Runtime.Serialization assembly, System.Xml namespace.

Trying to find out where this guy is located in DotNetCore or the new equivalent class (for cross framework serialization purposes).

Answer (score 0):

The [Reverse Package Search](https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) tool is your friend!

`System.Xml.UniqueId` lives in the [System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml) NuGet package, which is compatible with .NET Standard.